# Sign up page for iOS app not responding

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, firebase, firebase-authentication

I tried to make a sign up section for my application, however, when I click sign up, it seems to do nothing. I partly used my knowledge and a tutorial to build it, but when I click it, nothing happens.

I checked my logs to see if anything came up, but I don't see anything at all. I'm new to using Xcode and Swift, so I don't know if I made a stupid mistake or not, but here is my code.

I also have my Google plist and pods installed, so I don't think that's a problem.

SignUpController.swift

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import Firebase
import FirebaseAuth
import FirebaseDatabase

class SignUpController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var Email: UITextField!

@IBOutlet weak var Password: UITextField!

@IBAction func Create(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    let Email = self.Email.text!
    let Password = self.Password.text!


    if Email != "" && Password != "" {
        FIRAuth.auth()?.signIn(withEmail: Email, password: Password, completion: { (user, error) in
            if error == nil{
                FIREmailPasswordAuthProvider.credential(withEmail: Email, password: Password)
                self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
            }
            print("Error")
        })
    }
    else{
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: "Enter email and password!", preferredStyle: .alert)
        let action = UIAlertAction(title: "test", style: .default, handler: nil)
        alert.addAction(action)
        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    func Cancel(_ sender: AnyObject) {
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    Email.delegate = self
    Password.delegate = self
}
func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    textField.resignFirstResponder()
    return true
}
}
```

AppDelegate.swift

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import FirebaseDatabase

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

var window: UIWindow?

override init() {
    FIRApp.configure()
    FIRDatabase.database().persistenceEnabled = true
}


private func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    return true
}

@objc(applicationWillResignActive:) func applicationWillResignActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
    // Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
    // Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and throttle down OpenGL ES frame rates. Games should use this method to pause the game.
}

func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication) {
    // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later.
    // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.
}

func applicationWillEnterForeground(_ application: UIApplication) {
    // Called as part of the transition from the background to the active state; here you can undo many of the made on entering the background.
}

func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
    // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
}

func applicationWillTerminate(_ application: UIApplication) {
    // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
}


}
```

Comment: Hey Moo, are you sure you correctly connected the UIButton with the 'Create' IBAction?

Comment: I'm 100% sure my UIButton is connected to the Create IBAction, I move my mouse over the black dot next to the Create IBAction and it highlights the Create UIButton.

Comment: Put a print at the beginning of the Create() to see if the method gets called, then report back.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, where do I put the print? After the @IBAction func?

Comment: Yes after the @IBAction.  You can also use breakpoints instead of prints to check for things such as a method being called, and then you don't even have to rebuild.

Comment: I put this `@IBAction func printCreate(_ sender: AnyObject) {` and when i click create the app crashes. @Frankie @SickAustrian

Comment: Oh dear. Thats not what we meant. Put `print( "button was clicked")` at the beginning of the `Create` method. So you end up with `@IBAction func Create(_ sender: AnyObject) { print( "button was clicked") ... `.

Comment: Oh sorry i have no idea what I'm doing ;[ i added it and it printed my other thing where it says error enter an email or password

Comment: So the `Create` method gets called then after all.

Comment: Any idea what the problem is then if it's being called?

Comment: What happens if you enter an email and password and then click the button?

Comment: Nothing at all, the button is just pressed and that's it, I can press the button many times and it doesn't do anything. I can't seem to find anything in the logs and when I check firebase there has been no user or account that has been created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you are trying to sign in the user, instead of signing up the user.

Change

`FIRAuth.auth()?.signIn(withEmail: Email, password: Password, completion: { (user, error) in`

to

`FIRAuth.auth()?.createUser(withEmail: Email, password: Password, completion: { (user, error) in`

Comment: Thank you! Didn't see how i missed that before, so if i just put the same thing for a sign in page would it work?

Comment: In theory it should, but I don't know if there are other things that are broken right now. Can you check if my answer solves this for you? It could be a number of other things but this one seemed the most obvious at the moment.

Comment: Yeah it works perfectly! It was just that one exact mistake!

Comment: Great to hear that!